# Peek at next line, but don't consume it

Tags: awk, gawk

`getline` reads in the next line and increments the `NR` counter by 1. After using `getline`, `awk` resumes work with the next line. This is the desired behavior in most cases.

In my special situation I need only to peek the next line and depending on its content I read the next line or I need to backtrack one line.

How can I backtrack one line in `awk`? I tried setting the `NR` counter manually to `NR=NR-1` but this doesn't work. Or is there a method that only looks at the next line without changing `NR`?

I need a lookahead of one line. Simply saving the line in a variable and referring to it later does not work in this case. I am trying to implement a literate programming tool in `awk`, where a master file might contain many subfiles. Such a subfile begins with a line like `"% file:file1"`. The end of such a file is reached, if a line with a lower indentation or another line with a line like `"% file:file2"` is reached.

The rule set for all lines matching `/% file:/` is not used, when I have already read this line with getline. That's why I would like to reset `NR` to the previous line, then `awk` would read the line matching `/% file:/` again and the appropriate rule would be executed.

Comment: I developed a text-munging language called TXR which features pattern matching with implicit backtracking in both line-oriented ("vertical") and character oriented ("horizontal") matching modes. The lookahead depth is an arbitrary number of characters or lines. TXR is nearly ideal for the task of processing a literate programming notation. It's hard to give a directly relevant example; can you post a complete specification of the literate notation?

Answer (score 13):

This may approach what you're looking for and shouldn't be as expensive as the `sed` solution since AWK maintains a pointer into the file that `getline` opens.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {
         getline nextline < FILENAME
     }
     {
         getline nextline < FILENAME;
         print "currentline is:", $0;
         print "nextline is:   ", nextline
     }' input file
```

The first block reads the first line and wastes it.

In this form, `getline` doesn't set any variables such as `NR`, `FNR`, `NF` or `$0`. It only sets the variable that you supply (`nextline` in this case).

See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fFile) for some additional information.

Comment: Shame, this is seemingly GNU awk specific.

Comment: I checked your method with the following command `for i in {1..10} ; do echo $i ; done > tesxt2.txt && awk --posix  '{getline var < FILENAME ; print var,$i}' tesxt2.txt && rm tesxt2.txt` Unfortunately `getline` was not able to show the next line. Is this because of the missing `FNR == 1`?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately not,  `print var,$i` showed the same variables (1,1, 2,2 etc). That should be `print var,$0` but in both cases the output is not capturing `new & old` line

Comment: @AlexanderCska: On issue is that in your script, awk is printing `var,$i` and `i` is not set. If it were, it would print _field_ `i` because of the dollar sign. It should instead print `var,$0`. It just happens that an unset `i` is interpreted as zero and so it seems to do what you intend. But the main problem in your test is that you didn't include the first block from my answer (`FNR == 1 { ... }`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack and is fairly expensive, but for small files does give you a lookahead:

```
cmd="sed -n " NR + 1 "p " FILENAME; cmd | getline nextline
```

That will take the current value of NR and use sed to extract line NR + 1 from the input file.  This is expensive because sed will read through the entire file each time you do a lookahead (you can alleviate that slightly by adding a 'q' command to sed).  The variable nextline will be set to the next line of the file, and will be blank on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Just creat a variable to store your last line.

```
BEGIN { last = "" }
```

Then check and set the last line in your next iteration.