# Search for first item in line, then print line and following line

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I am trying to search a file for a name, and then print the following line.  I originally solved it like this:

`grep -A 1 "searchterm" filename`

However, this searches for `searchterm` everywhere in the line; this is a problem because I only want matches in the first part of the line.

For example, if I'm looking for `1234` in the following file:

```
4567 otherstuff 1234
wrongsecondline
1234 otherstuff
rightsecondline
```

It's going to find `4567 otherstuff 1234` and `wrongsecondline`, when really I wanted `1234 otherstuff` and `rightsecondline`.

Any thoughts on how to search only for the first item in a line, and then print that line and the second line?  Thanks!

Comment: grep accepts regular expressions as search terms. You should prefix the term with ^ and end it with $ e.g. 
^1234 otherstuff$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` to print both the matching and the following lines:

```
$ egrep -w -A1 "^1234" filename
1234 otherstuff
rightsecondline
```

Using `awk` to achieve the same as the above<sup>†</sup>:

```
$ awk '$1=="1234"{print;getline;print}' filename
1234 otherstuff
rightsecondline
```

Using `grep` to *only* print the line following a match (notice `<` before `filename`):

```
$ grep -w -H --label=dummy -A1 '^1234' <filename | sed -ne 's#^dummy-##p'
rightsecondline
```

Using `awk` to achieve the same as the above<sup>†</sup>:

```
$ awk '$1=="1234"{getline;print}' filename
rightsecondline
```

<sup>†provided no two consecutive lines contain the search term, and that the last line in the file does not contain the search term</sup>

---

If you expect two or more consecutive lines to contain the search term, e.g.

```
4567 otherstuff 1234
wrongsecondline
1234 otherstuff once
1234 otherstuff again
rightsecondline
```

...then using `awk` statefully to achieve the same output as `grep -A1`:

```
$ awk 'pr_after{print;pr_after=0}$1=="1234"{print;pr_after=1}' filename
1234 otherstuff once
1234 otherstuff again
rightsecondline
```

...and using `awk` statefully to always print the line following a match, even if that line is a match itself:

```
$ awk 'pr_after{print;pr_after=0}$1=="1234"{pr_after=1}' filename
1234 otherstuff again
rightsecondline
```

...or using `awk` statefully to only print the non-matching line immediately following one or more matching lines, achieving the same output as `grep -H | sed` above:

```
$ awk '$1=="1234"{pr_after=1;next}pr_after{print;pr_after=0}' filename
rightsecondline
```

---

In the examples above, `$1=="1234"{...}` is a [pattern/action rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started) that means *if the first column equals the text `1234` then do ...*, `pr_after{...}` means *if variable `pr_after` is set to some non-zero non-empty value then do ...*, [`getline`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) means *read the next line and continue execution with the statement after getline*, whereas [`next`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html#Next-Statement) means *read the next line and restart evaluation at the first pattern*.

Comment: awesome!  both work perfectly.  i like the grep solution because it's faster.  thanks!!

Comment: Do not use getline unless you fully understand all of it's many caveats, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline. You already discovered one of them by not being able to match consecutive lines containing 1234, now try it with a file where the last line is 1234 and you'll see another one (that matching line will be printed [twice] instead of the non-existent line after it).

Comment: @EdMorton I'd hardly call them caveats, I actually fail to see how *else* you'd expect `getline` to work (like a [non-existent `peekline`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232780/peek-at-next-line-but-dont-consume-it)?.) Testing for the return value of `getline` (e.g. `if(getline)print`) deals just fine with the last-line-in-file scenario, but again, the `getline` examples above target well-formed input (e.g. each matching type A record always followed by a type B record) and are **meant to be simple** in that context. The stateful examples are correct in all cases but are more complex.

Comment: getline works the way it works, I'm not saying it should change, just that you have to be aware of how it works if you're going to use it. In this case, yes, a test on it's return code at a minimum would be appropriate to get around the immediate issues. You had said that the awk/getline approach achieved the same as the grep approach but that's not the case in non-obvious but very real situations so it's worth stating what those are so the OP doesn't take the stated grep-equivalence as precise.

Comment: By the way, `if (getline)` is not how to test for a successful getline return, you need to test for it's return code being greater than zero as it can be less than zero for some failure cases. Again, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Answer (score 1):

Using grep is perfectly reasonable for this assuming you don't want to enhance the selection criteria, but FYI the following idioms describe how to use awk to select a range of records given a specific pattern to match:

```
a) Print all records from some pattern:

    awk '/pattern/{f=1}f' file

b) Print all records after some pattern:

    awk 'f;/pattern/{f=1}' file

c) Print the Nth record after some pattern:

    awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' file

d) Print every record except the Nth record after some pattern:

    awk 'c&&!--c{next}/pattern/{c=N}1' file

e) Print the N records after some pattern:

    awk 'c&&c--;/pattern/{c=N}' file

f) Print every record except the N records after some pattern:

    awk 'c&&c--{next}/pattern/{c=N}1' file

g) Print the N records from some pattern:

    awk '/pattern/{c=N}c&&c--' file
```

I changed the variable name from "f" for "found" to "c" for "count" where appropriate as that's more expressive of what the variable actually IS.

So for this case you could use idiom "c" above  as:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/1234/{c=1}' file
```