# awk: Check if a number is in between two numbers

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file of below format

```
02 Jul 2016 00:00:00 2736359
02 Jul 2016 00:02:00 2736594
02 Jul 2016 00:04:00 2736828
02 Jul 2016 00:06:00 2737068
02 Jul 2016 00:08:00 2737303
02 Jul 2016 00:10:00 2737542
02 Jul 2016 00:12:00 2737775
02 Jul 2016 00:14:00 2738011
02 Jul 2016 00:16:00 2738251
02 Jul 2016 00:18:00 2738483
```

Where the first column is the time stamp and second is a number. Given an input 2737778, I want the output to be "02 Jul 2016 00:12:00 and 02 Jul 2016 00:14:00" as 2737778 falls in between 2737775 and 2738011. Can I do this in awk? Is it possible to compare a number in current line with next line?

Answer (score 2):

another similar `awk`

```
awk -v n=2737778 'n<=$NF{if(p) print p; print; exit} {p=$0}' file

02 Jul 2016 00:12:00 2737775
02 Jul 2016 00:14:00 2738011
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. But the problem is though the numbers are in increasing order it resets after a week. So I'm afraid that there would a corner case. Can we check if the number is inbetween instead of just checking <=?

Comment: That's exactly what the script does as long as the file is sorted. Test the corner cases, there are two of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to read ahead in awk, see [Peek at next line, but don't consume it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232780/peek-at-next-line-but-dont-consume-it). Here is another way to do it.

```
awk '{ if (NR == 1) { save = $0; prtsw = 1 }
       else if (prtsw == 1 && 2737778 < $5) {
                print save
                print $0
                prtsw = 0
            }
            else { save = $0 }
    }' abetween.txt
```